# Creating text boxes with leader arrows in jekyll markdown

Tags: javascript, jekyll, github-pages

I would like to ask whether there exists a way of annotating code using text boxes and leader arrows in `jekyll` for a `github-pages` site. I am referring to something like the following:

[image]

I am open to diving into the source html and doing something nifty with SVG as well, since I am starting to think this cannot be done directly in the markdown...